# ¿Como seleccionar items creando un rectangulo con Angular 2 / 4?

Tags: javascript, css, select, angular

Tengo un gran problema con algo que he estado intentando hacer desde hace tiempo.

Tengo este código Angular 2 / 4 en Plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/0DAFaBQiMez8uhxPZQgB?p=preview) al cual se puede seleccionar una o mas tarjetas arrastrando el mouse en las tarjetas pero no es la exacta implementación que me gustaría tener ya que contiene bugs y no es lo que quiero exactamente.

Encontré este código JS (http://jsfiddle.net/JancoBH/weLrw4ze/2/) y me gustaría implementarlo en ese Plunker con Angular 2 para poder seleccionar lo que se encuentre dentro del rectángulo.

> Alguien intento ayudarme y el resultado fue este
>   (plnkr.co/edit/JtkBSRhPNxAphLOtYFWa?p=preview) y me cuesta poder
>   arreglarlo.